# What does (?ui) mean in a Python regex?

Tags: python, regex

The Python Fuzzy Wuzzy library includes the following regex:

```
regex = re.compile(r"(?ui)\W")
return regex.sub(u" ", a_string)
```

(https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/blob/master/fuzzywuzzy/string_processing.py#L17)

This replaces any non-alphanumeric in a_string with a space.

What does the (?ui) bit do though? It seems to work fine without it.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *u* is the [unicode flag](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) and *i* is the [ignore case flag](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE).

The unicode flag makes \w, \W, \b, \B, \d, \D, \s and \S dependent on the Unicode character properties database.  For example:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', u'The answer is \u0664\u0662')         # No flag
[]

>>> re.findall(r'(?u)\d+', u'The answer is \u0664\u0662')     # With unicode flag
[u'\u0664\u0662']
```

The ignore case flag performs case-insensitive matching.   Expressions like `[A-Z]` will match lowercase letters as well. This is not affected by the current locale.  For example:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[a-z]+', 'HELLO world')         # No flag
['world']

>>> re.findall(r'(?i)[a-z]+', 'HELLO world')     # With ignore case flag
['HELLO', 'world']
```

Answer (score 6):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

> (`?iLmsux`)
>   (One or more letters from the set `'i', 'L', 'm', 's', 'u', 'x'`.) The group matches the empty string; the letters set the corresponding flags:

- `re.I` (ignore case),
- `re.L` (locale dependent),
- `re.M` (multi-line),
- `re.S` (dot matches all),
- `re.U` (Unicode dependent),
- `re.X` (verbose),

for the entire regular expression. (The flags are described in Module Contents.) This is useful if you wish to include the flags as part of the regular expression, instead of passing a flag argument to the `re.compile()` function.

> Note that the `(?x)` flag changes how the expression is parsed. It should be used first in the expression string, or after one or more whitespace characters. If there are non-whitespace characters before the flag, the results are undefined.

**tl;dr** `(?u)` uses unicode in the regular expression and `(?i)` ignores case

Comment: this answer also explains why there are 2 ways to do the same thing